# Can chloride donate an electron pair to silver(I)?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, bond

[According to the Lewis dot structure of $\ce{Cl-}$](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iqH0amMEoZM), $\ce{Cl-}$ has octet fulfilled and should be able to donate a pair of electrons as it is a Lewis base. [The Lewis dot structure of $\ce{Ag+}$ seems weird](https://study.com/cimages/multimages/16/fig_31924935618410608243.jpg). As it is a Lewis acid, I should assume that it can accept a pair of electrons.

However, now the problem arises. If $\ce{Cl-}$ donates a pair of electrons to $\ce{Ag+}$, there should be a coordinate covalent bond between them. In reality, $\ce{AgCl}$ is an ionic compound, and there is no such coordinate covalent bond, so I'm a bit confused.

In simpler words, $\ce{Ag+}$ is a lewis acid.$\ce{Cl-}$ is a lewis base. Can $\ce{Cl-}$ donate an electron pair to $\ce{Ag+}$?

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Cl- ion is capable of donating electron pairs. See the [question](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Map%3A_General_Chemistry_(Petrucci_et_al.)/16%3A_Acids_and_Bases/16.9%3A_Lewis_Acids_and_Bases#:~:text=BeCl2%20%2B%202%20Cl%E2%88%92%20%E2%86%92%20BeCl42%E2%88%92) (...)

Comment: (...), and then see the [answer](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Map%3A_General_Chemistry_(Petrucci_et_al.)/16%3A_Acids_and_Bases/16.9%3A_Lewis_Acids_and_Bases#:~:text=The%20chloride%20ion%20contains%20four%20lone%20pairs.%20In%20this%20reaction%2C%20each%20chloride%20ion%20donates%20one%20lone%20pair%20to%20BeCl2%2C%20which%20has%20only%20four%20electrons%20around%20Be.%20Thus%20the%20chloride%20ions%20are%20Lewis%20bases%2C%20and%20BeCl2%20is%20the%20Lewis%20acid.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If $\mathrm{Cl^-}$ donates a pair of electrons to $\mathrm{Ag^+}$, there should be a coordinate covalent bond between them. In reality, $\mathrm{AgCl}$ is an ionic compound, and there is no such coordinate covalent bond, so I'm a bit confused.

Yes, there is no dative bond between them. $\mathrm{AgCl}$ is an ionic compound with partially covalent character. So, the bond between $\mathrm{Ag^+}$ and $\mathrm{Cl^-}$ will be a simple ionic bond.

> In simpler words, $\mathrm{Ag^+}$ is a lewis acid. $\mathrm{Cl^-}$ is a lewis base. Can $\mathrm{Cl^-}$ donate an electron pair to $\mathrm{Ag^+}$ ?

Yes, $\mathrm{Ag^+}$ can act as Lewis acid and $\mathrm{Cl^-}$ can act as Lewis base. But actually $\mathrm{Cl^-}$ can't donate an electron pair to $\mathrm{Ag^+}$. This is because both are weak Lewis acids and bases.

---

> If $\mathrm{Ag^+}$ can't accept an electron pair, how can it be a Lewis acid?

It may not accept an electron pair in this case. It doesn't mean that it isn't a Lewis acid. Lewis acid doens't mean that it can accept an electron pair from any type of ligands. For example, $\mathrm{Na^+}$ is also a Lewis acid. Eventhough it is a Lewis acid it frequently forms ionic compounds rather than forming covalent compounds. 
I can give an example where $\mathrm{Ag^+}$ can act as a Lewis acid. $\mathrm{AgCl}$ is insoluble in water but it is soluble in ammonia. This is because $\mathrm{AgCl}$ forms complex with $\mathrm{NH_3}$ which accounts for its solubility. During formation of complex $\mathrm{NH_3}$ will donate an electron pair to $\mathrm{Ag^+}$. So here it acts as a Lewis acid. I can give its equation -
$$ \ce{ Ag+ + 2NH3 -> [Ag(NH3)2]+}$$

Comment: According to the Wikipedia definition, a Lewis acid is one that can accept an electron pair. If Ag+ can't accept an electron pair, how can it be a Lewis acid?

Comment: Sorry, it is not actually a question posted here. It just for your clarification.

Comment: Okay I will include answers to this comments in my post.

Comment: @Infinite is it always true that weak lewis bases don't form dative bonds with lewis acids?

Comment: @Arpan no, it is not true. If cation has high charge density for example Cr(III) ion can act as LA in presence of Cl- ion.

Comment: @Mithoron I wonna know where I was incorrect ?

Comment: Easier to tell where you were correct, just about last paragraph. Cl *does* coordinate Ag all the time.

Comment: Correct? You said it was thoroughly incorrect, right?

Comment: Yeah, Cl will coordinate to Ag all the time. If it doesn't coordinate, then formation of the compound would be senseless.

Comment: @Mithoron Is there a coordinate covalent bond between Ag+ and Cl- in AgCl?

Comment: Oh, why you even try to answer such a lame question. AgCl is more covalent then ionic. Coordinate bonds are no different then "non-coordinate". Cl− **can** donate an electron pair to Ag+. And they **aren't** "weak" Lewis acid and base. There's no single scale of strength of them anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Chlorine $\ce{(Cl)}$ needs to gain one electron in order to complete its octet (forming the $\ce{Cl-}$ ion), while silver $\ce{(Ag)}$ needs to lose one electron (forming the $\ce{Ag+}$ ion). This is why it is an ionic reaction. Unlike in a covalent bond, the electrons aren't shared; they are donated, forming *dissociated ions* in solution:

$$\ce{Ag^+(aq) + Cl^-(aq) <=>> AgCl (v)}$$

Note that $\ce{AgCl}$ generally forms as a precipitate. The reaction is technically reversible, but only proceeds to a very limited extent in solution.

Indeed, as you noted, $\ce{Ag+}$ is a Lewis acid, and $\ce{Cl-}$ is a Lewis base. Therefore, a Lewis acid-base adduct *can* form between the two. In fact, this is precisely why $\ce{AgCl}$ precipitates in solution! The $\ce{Ag+}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$ ions hold tightly together, forming a bond that has an extremely high covalent character. The bond between them is very difficult to break apart, which is why $\ce{AgCl}$ forms as a precipitate rather than being solubilized in water.

Comment: [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_acids_and_bases), "A Lewis acid (named for the American physical chemist Gilbert N. Lewis) is a chemical species that contains an empty orbital which is capable of accepting an electron pair from a Lewis base to form a Lewis adduct." If Ag+ can't accept an electron **pair**, how is it a Lewis acid?

Comment: Thank you for responding, sir! However, I'm genuinely confused as to why Ag+ is a Lewis acid if it can't accept an electron **pair**.